# Horizontal scrollbar if the content of a <div> won't fit the width

Tags: html, css

I am using an `absolute` `div` so I can overlap one `div` from another. The `div` that overlaps is the `absolute` one (`.content`). However, if the overlapped `div` (`.left`) doesn't fit the screen, a horizontal scroll bar doesn't appear of course. How can I make the horizontal scroll bar automatically appear if its contents doesn't fit the given width? Here is the css:

```
.left {
    width: 70%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    overflow-x:auto;
}
.content {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 130px;
    background-color: #2b3e50;
    border-left-width:5px;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-left-color:#153450;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Please help me figure this out.

**EDIT** 
Here is the `div` structure:

```
<div class="topbar">
    <div class="fill">
        <div class="container">
            Home
            <ul class="nav">
                <li> One </li>
                <li> Two </li>
                <li> Three </li>
                <li> Four </li>
            </ul>
            <p align="right">Log-out </p>
        </div>                
    </div>
</div>
<div id="loader" class="left" style="border-right-width:15px;">

</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="content">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="span14">
                @content
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<script>
$("#loader").html('<object data="@routes.Tags.map(false)" />');
</script>
```

**EDIT**

 I surrounded the `left` div with a `parent` div.

```
<div class="parent">
            <div id="loader" class="left" style="border-right-width:15px;">

            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span14">
                        @content
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

With the following `css` for `parent`.

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

But still doesn't show a scrollbar.

Comment: Your HTML structure will be helpfull

Comment: give position relative to parent div and then try.

Comment: Thanks @user3657431 I edited my question. That completely slipped my mind.

Comment: Thanks @ketan but there is no parent `div`.

Comment: The width is 820px @Pete

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the question.  Are you wanting a scrollbar on left if content is too large?

Comment: Yes @Pete. I edited my question. The `div` that overlaps is the absolute one (`.content`). And the overlapped div (`.left`) doesn't fit the screen and no horizontal scrollbar shows.

Answer (score 2):

In your html `left` is not child of `content` you can't make it scroll. 
If you have parent > child then just use `position: relative` on parent block.
Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/4swN9/

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited my question. The `div` that overlaps is the absolute one (`.content`). And the overlapped div (`.left`) doesn't fit the screen and no horizontal scrollbar shows.